# Simplifying $\frac{(\ln a)^3+(\ln b)^3+(\ln c)^3+(\ln d)^3}{\ln ab\;(\ln c\ln d-\ln a\ln b)}$ for positive reals with $abcd=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

The problem is as follows:

> Given the condition for $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ to be real positive numbers whose product equals to $1$, find the value of $B$.
>
> $$B=\frac{(\ln a)^3+(\ln b)^3+(\ln c)^3+(\ln d)^3}{\ln ab\cdot\left(\ln c\cdot\ln d-\ln a\cdot\ln b\right)}$$
>
> The alternatives given in my book are as follows:
>
> $\begin{array}{ll}
> 1.&\textrm{4}\\
> 2.&\textrm{2}\\
> 3.&\textrm{3}\\
> 4.&\textrm{6}\\
> \end{array}$

I'm not very sure exactly how to simplify this expression. So far what I've could spot was this:

$abcd=1$

$\ln ab=\ln a + \ln b$

$(\ln a + \ln b)(\ln^2a -\ln a \ln b+\ln^2b)$

$(\ln c + \ln d)(\ln^2c -\ln c \ln d+\ln^2d)$

Taking the natural logarithm to the mentioned expression would become into:

$\ln abcd = \ln 1 = 0$

$\ln a + \ln b + \ln c + \ln d = 0$

But from here is where it becomes quite confusing on how to organize these expressions so that can achieve simplication of the before mentioned equation. Can someone help me here?.

From what I could also spot is:

$(\ln c + \ln d)((\ln c + \ln d)^2 - 3 \ln c \ln d)$

$-(\ln a+\ln b)((\ln a + \ln b)^2 - 3 \ln c \ln d)$

But that's how far I went. Does it exist other manipulation which can be done?

Comment: What if the denominator is $0$?

Comment: I used $a,b,c,(-a-b-c)$ instead of $\ln a,\ln b,\ln c,\ln d$ (like "variable change") to get [$3$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%5E3%2Bb%5E3%2Bc%5E3%2B%28-a-b-c%29%5E3%29%2F%28%28a%2Bb%29*%28c*%28-a-b-c%29-a*b%29%29).

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang There are steps in between which is a **must** to understand this simplication. Can you explain from what I've done, how exactly $CD-AB$ simplifies with what's in the numerator?. Can you help me with this part please?.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang It seems that I've reached the same as you but I overlooked the final step was just assemble it in the numerator and that was it. I suggest that you may post an answer?.

Comment: @Yourong'DZR'Zang $A+B\neq C+D$, maybe it is a typo for $(A+B)= -(C+D)$ or $(A+B)^2= (C+D)^2$?

Comment: @user Indeed that is a typo. Thank you for pointing this out. However, I can't edit my comment now so I will just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Following the idea given in the comments, let $a=e^A$, $b=e^B$, $c=e^C$, $d=e^D$ then

$$\frac{A^3+B^3+C^3+D^3}{(A+B)\cdot\left(CD-AB\right)}=\frac{(A+B)(A^2-BC+B^2)+(C+D)(C^2-CD+D^2)}{(A+B)\cdot\left(CD-AB\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{(A+B)(A^2-AB+B^2)-(A+B)(C^2-CD+D^2)}{(A+B)\cdot\left(CD-AB\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{(A^2-AB+B^2)-(C^2-CD+D^2)}{\left(CD-AB\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{(CD-AB)+A^2+B^2-C^2-D^2}{\left(CD-AB\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{(CD-AB)+2CD-2AB}{\left(CD-AB\right)}=3$$

using that

$$A+B=-(C+D) \implies \\(A+B)^2=(C+D)^2 \implies A^2+B^2-C^2-D^2=2CD-2AB$$